# Remove double vertices

Tags: mesh, vertices

When removing double vertices in 2.8, I first ensure that normals are consistent and I then merge by distance. If I then recalculate normals there are further double vertices!. If I repeat the process several times, all double vertices are eventually eliminated. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can't reproduce this.. is it something to do with partial selections? Are you selecting all before merging? Or checking 'unselected' in the merge options?

Comment: If @Robin Betts' comment doesn't fix your problem, would you please add your .blend file?

Comment: This occurred a couple of times when importing a complex mesh as FBX. I will try to reproduce the mesh setup and post it.